# radius rectangle with dynamic size

Tags: android, drawrectangle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFy94.png)
How do I create a rectangle with a text object inside, so that the width of the rectangle elastically reshapes to the width of the text (rahter than the regular text-wrap in shape behaviour)?

Answer (score 0):

Add a border to Android TextView we need to create an XML containing shape as a rectangle file under the drawable's folder and set it as background to the TextView.  tag is used to set the border width and color.

**textview_border.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
 <stroke
   android:width="2dp"
   android:color="#000000" />
 </shape>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:padding="10dp" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
      tools:ignore="HardcodedText">

<TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="30dp"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:background="@drawable/textview_border"
      android:gravity="center"
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Result**
[image]

Comment: hello kartik and thank you for answer.yes the point was create adrawable and set it as a background for text view